# Copying the Matching Columns from CSV File

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, dictionary

**Input:**

I have two csv files (file1.csv and file2.csv).

file1 looks like:

```
ID,Name,Gender
1,Smith,M
2,John,M
```

file2 looks like:

```
name,gender,city,id
```

**Problem:**

I want to compare the header of file1 with file2 and copy the data of the matching columns.  The header in file1 need to be in lowercase prior to finding the matching columns in file2.

**Output:**

the output should be like this:

```
name,gender,city,id  # name,gender,and id are the only matching columns btw file1 and file2 
Smith,M, ,1          # the data copied for name, gender, and id columns 
John,M, ,2
```

I have tried the following code so far:

```
import csv

file1 = csv.DictReader(open("file1.csv"))   #reading file1.csv
file1_Dict = {} # the dictionary of lists that will store the keys and values as list 
for row in file1: 
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
        file1_Dict.setdefault(column,[]).append(value)

for key in file1_Dict: # converting the keys of the dictionary to lowercase
    file1_Dict[key.lower()] = file1_Dict.pop(key)

file2 = open("file2.csv")    #reading file2.csv
file2_Dict ={}               # store the keys into a dictionary with empty values
for row2 in file2:
    row2 = row2.split(",")
    for i in row2:
        file2_Dict[i] = ""
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a crack on this problem using python without taking performance into consideration. Took me quite a while, phew!

This is my solution.

```
import csv

csv_data1_filepath = './file1.csv'
csv_data2_filepath = './file2.csv'

def main():

    # import nem config and data into memory
    data1 = list(csv.reader(file(csv_data1_filepath, 'r')))
    data2 = list(csv.reader(file(csv_data2_filepath, 'r')))

    file1_header = data1[0][:] # Get f1 header
    file2_header = data2[0][:] # Get f1 header
    lowered_file1_header = [item.lower() for item in file1_header] # lowercase it
    lowered_file2_header = [item.lower() for item in file2_header] # do it for header 2 anyway

    col_index_dict = {}
    for column in lowered_file1_header:
        if column in file2_header:
            col_index_dict[column] = lowered_file1_header.index(column)
        else:
            col_index_dict[column] = -1 # mark as column that will not be worked on later

    for column in lowered_file2_header:
        if not column in lowered_file1_header:
            col_index_dict[column] = -1 # mark as column that will not be worked on later

    # build header
    output = [col_index_dict.keys()]
    is_header = True

    for row in data1:
        if is_header is False:
            rowData = []
            for column in col_index_dict:
                column_index = col_index_dict[column]
                if column_index != -1:
                    rowData.append(row[column_index])
                else:
                    rowData.append('')
            output.append(rowData)
        else:
            is_header = False

    print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will give you the output of:

```
[
    ['gender', 'city', 'id', 'name'], 
    ['M', '', '1', 'Smith'], 
    ['M', '', '2', 'John']
]
```

Note that the output kind of lost its ordering but this should be fixable by using the ordered dictionary instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are awesome!  Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Python for this.  This is a task for SQL.

[SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) supports CSV Import.  Take the below steps to get the desired output:

- Download and install SQLite Browser
- Create a new Database
- Import both CSV's as tables (let's say the table names are file1 and file2, respectively)

Now, you can decide how you want to match the data sets.  If you only want to match the files on ID, then you can do something like:

```
select *
from file1 f1
  inner join file2 f2
    on f1.id = f2.id
```

If you want to match on every column, you can do something like:

```
select *
from file1 f1
  inner join file2 f2
    on f1.id = f2.id and f1.name = f2.name and f1.gender = f2.gender
```

Finally, simply export the query results back to a CSV.

I spent a lot of time myself trying to perform tasks like this with scripting languages.  The benefit of using SQL is that you simply tell what you want to match on, and then let the database do the optimization for you.  Generally, it ends up doing the matching faster than any code I could write.

In case you're interested, python also has a sqlite module that comes out-of-the-box.  I've gravitated towards using this as my source for data in python scripts for the above reason, and I simply import the CSV's required in SQLite browser before running the python script.

Comment: Don't bring a knife to a gunfight, and don't bring a dictionary to a database fight.

Comment: @Alex Barry 
Thanks! That is a way to approach it ... But what if you have a large number of columns to match on?  Would not be a headache to join them in the select statement?

Comment: Yes it might be, but I would think less of a headache than writing an entire script:).  If you're really concerned, you could always write a python script to generate a SQL statement based on the CSV/Table Header, then execute that using the sqlite module